CBS Storybreak stories
There are two episodes from CBS Storybreak that I'd like to know the title of the books the episode was based off of so I can share with my children.  I can break this out into two separate questions if needed.
I've looked for episode guides online but haven't found what I'm looking for.

It was the Pied Piper but from what I've read on wikipedia, there are many variations so hopefully this helps ID the book.
Basically same story as the Pied Piper but in this case, there were two kids who were nice to him, a boy and a girl.  After he gets screwed by the mayor (or whoever), he comes back to the bakery where the boy worked at and order enough buns for each kid in the town.  He tells the boy to bake the rolls with some powder or something that later makes all the kids hallucinate and/or listen to him when he played his pipe.  He tells the boy to destroy two rolls so the two kids he liked wouldn't hallucinate but the boy just puts the rolls aside and unfortunately the girl finds them, eats hers and starts hallucinating.
The second story I don't have as many details.  If I remember correctly, some kids run into some creatures who lived underground like moles but they were a single color (purple I want to say...or maybe green).  They kept repeating one word since their language wasn't very evolved or sophisticated.  I forget why the kids go down the "rabbit hole" but they do.

This is all I remember from the episodes.  I'll keep looking for episode guides and post here if I find anything substantial.

hey. I don't know if you're still interested in this but the two episodes you were asking about are called "What Happened In Hamelin" and "The Secret World Of Og". Hope that helps you in your search.

Thank you!!  The 2nd title sounds about right.  The first one, I'll take your word for it.  Where did you find the episode names?

I know the second episode is titled "The Secret World Of Og" because the episode can be found on Youtube. As for "What Happened In Hamelin", I own a copy of the book and have seen other people refer to the episode by the same title. Just between you and me, I wish you the best of British luck if you're hoping to track the Pied Piper episode down. I've searched high and low, discovering only that it doesn't appear to be online. Let me know if your own quest turns up a more favorable result.
